# My project's architecture is Micro Services architecture?

Tags: microservices

In my project we start the day with one SOD script which does some start of the day functionalities. then it generates event on its completion which triggers few more processes which starts data loading and such a chain of processes keeps on running sometimes by event generation or sometimes doing status updates in database.

all processes are independent services developed in different languages ? Does this kind of architecture categorized as Micro services architecture OR this is more like event driven system ? How to differentiate them

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a whole lot of information to go on here, but i'll try to answer based on what you have given. You mentioned that you have separate processes that operate independently. Are these literally multiple processes running within a machine or are you referring to individual services, such as multiple APIs ? Do the individual services rely on data from another service ? It sounds like you are saying one service calls another and so forth.

Generally speaking, a microservice architecture consists of multiple, separate services (APIs, background services, etc.) that each contribute their own "piece" to an overall application. In Domain-Driven-Design terminology, each of these pieces are referred to as a bounded-context. Each service should operate autonomously, own it's data (multiple services should not share one big database) and stay within the specific bounded-context for which it is designed for. Each of these services runs independently, many times using something like Kubernetes or some other type of container orchestrator. Then a client application (i.e. web UI) can then make requests through something like an API-Gateway. The gateway can then take that request, call the individual services it needs to and then aggregate or build a response to send back to the client. Each service contributes it's own piece of the puzzle and when put together they make up the overall application.

This is a very simplified explanation, since this topic is huge, so don't take what I say as a specific definition. The whole idea of microservices is really just a set of principles that should be followed, not a specific blueprint for how to design an application's architecture. I can recommend Microsoft's e-book on Containerized Microservice Applications, if you want to do the research to really get a better idea of this topic. Also, my experience with microservices is mainly with web related apps or systems, so maybe someone with other experience can help more.